# error trying to create a generic event handler raiser

Tags: asp.net, events, generics, event-handling

I have a set of events of the same signature , so I'm trying to create a generic raising method to be used for them all .

```
protected virtual void RaiseEvent<T>(EventHandler<T> eventToRaise, T eventArgs)
{
    if (eventToRaise != null)
    {
        try
        {
            eventToRaise(this, eventArgs);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("a problem accured while raising event : " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

but I get this error when trying to compile :

```
The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'TEventArgs' in the generic type or method 'System.EventHandler<TEventArgs>'. There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'T' to 'System.EventArgs'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the generic type constraint `where` to your signature:

```
protected virtual void RaiseEvent<T>(EventHandler<T> eventToRaise, T eventArgs) 
    where T : EventArgs
```

Comment: thank you , would this still works if I send subclasses of EventArgs as T ?